# How to connect to specific port on MySQL on namenode using Sqoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I got a problem statement in a test as below:

1. There is a file `/user/abc/weather/sfo_weather.csv`
2. There is MySQL database named `flightinfo` on the namenode machine. It contains a table named `weather`.
3. Use Sqoop to export the weather directory to the weather table in MySQL on the port `3306` on the namenode machine. Username for MySQL is `root` and password is `Hadoop.7`

I know how to export to `localhost`.

Can anyone tell how to export to `3306` port of namenode machine ?

Answer (score -1):

Take the hostname of the name node and try to give the same in the command to export.